# Custom entity extraction in R using openNLP

Tags: r, nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am currently using openNLP (openNLPmodels.en) to extract biographical information about different high ranking executives. I can extract dates, organizations, people and locations,  however I want to extract a list of job roles. I have a list of job roles and I was just wondering if I can do a custom entity recognition? Or something of the sort and how I would go about doing such a thing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the crfsuite R package for this: https://github.com/bnosac/crfsuite